# What are the regulations for lighting fixtures around an airport?

Tags: airport, airport-lighting

I work for a company that is right next to an Air Force base and we were wondering what and if there are regulations for the lighting fixtures that we can install on our lot since we have a couple of lights that are out of service and we were looking into upgrading them to LEDs

what is the temperature limit etc etc

I don't know much about aircraft regulation so i get lost in all the documents.

thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just to be clear, your company is *outside* the Air Force base and you want to make sure that any lighting in your parking lot is legal and doesn't interfere with aircraft operations. Is that correct? And which country are you in?

Comment: Yes!

we are located in the U.S.

Comment: Have you considered walking next door and asking? I know it's not as easy to get on a military installation as it used to be, but if you pick a quiet time (living next door, it should be easy to figure out when that it), I'm sure you could chat with the MPs at the guard post, tell them your need and ask who you should contact. You'll probably get a phone number for the base commander or someone similar who will point you in the right direction.

Comment: If this were a public use airport I'd say make a plan, make some drawings, and then contact the tower and talk to somebody. Odds are you would get directed to the local FSDO, but its unlikely you would have problems if the airport doesn't have any deed restrictions on your property. In the case of the US Air Force I agree with @FreeMan, see if you can get the number of the base commander and ask directly, they really don't have to follow FAA airport rules (although they usually do).

Comment: Thank you for the response @FreeMan but i went next door and they couldnt tell me that information!

Comment: It was worth a shot. Good on ya' for asking them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start you off there's these two:

[14 CFR Part 139](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=1a42a56e3a67e77518c754196673f1f6&mc=true&n=pt14.3.139&r=PART&ty=HTML#sp14.3.139.a) - Certification of Airports and

[14 CFR Part 157](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=1a42a56e3a67e77518c754196673f1f6&mc=true&n=pt14.3.157&r=PART&ty=HTML) - Notice of Construction, Alteration, Activation and Deactivation of Airports.

Part 139.311 covers all the lighting related requirements.

Part 157 is there just so you can inform the FAA about the changes you're going to make in the airport.

for specifics about LED lights, I would suggest looking for Advisory Circulars with LED lighting for airports in particular.

Comment: So i read the documents and it appears that they answer the question for lights on the field not outside

we are looking at a lighting fixture with temperature 4000k and 21000 lumens